# Modify the size of a column in SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to modify the size of this column "Description" in the table "Information":
the column "Description" is varchar(200) I want to increase the size to varchar(2000) without deleting the column or the table.

PS: I am using Oracle SQL Developer

Comment: Hint:  `alter table`.

Comment: I do not want to delete the table, alter table will delete the table

Comment: _" alter table will delete the table"_  Not true.  Where did you get that piece of incredibly wrong mis-information?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do that by modifying the column:

```
alter table INFORMATION modify DESCRIPTION varchar(2000);
```

Comment: the table is deleted :/ I could not find it

Comment: If you're lucky, and you have the Recycle Bin on, you can try to retrieve the table from there:

`flashback table <SchemaName>.INFORMATION to before drop;`

Otherwise, the only thing left to do, is to recreate the table, this time with the correct `VARCAHR2` value for the `DESCRIPTION` column.

Comment: I have another database on which I am working, how can I modify the size without altering the table ?

Comment: `alter table` is the only way, it will update your column from a `VARCHAR(200)` to `VARCHAR(2000)` the syntax is the same as above: `alter table <TableName> modify <ColumnName> varchar(2000);` - Of course change the table and column name if they're different on the other database.

Comment: Yes, @EdwardKirk is right, `ALTER TABLE` is the only way, and I've used it thousands of times without the table being deleted. What's going on?

Comment: _"the table is deleted :/ I could not find it "_  Then you've done something else with it.  The ALTER TABLE didn't do it.

Answer (score 0):

Just to prove that the table doesn't disappear:

```
CREATE TABLE INFORMATION (DESCRIPTION VARCHAR2(200));
-- Table INFORMATION created.

SELECT table_name, column_name, data_type, char_length 
  FROM user_tab_columns  
 WHERE table_name = 'INFORMATION';

TABLE_NAME   COLUMN_NAME   DATA_TYPE  CHAR_LENGTH
INFORMATION  DESCRIPTION   VARCHAR2           200
```

Now, drum roll please...

```
ALTER TABLE information MODIFY description VARCHAR2(2000);
-- Table INFORMATION altered.

SELECT table_name, column_name, data_type, char_length 
  FROM user_tab_columns  
 WHERE table_name = 'INFORMATION';

TABLE_NAME   COLUMN_NAME   DATA_TYPE  CHAR_LENGTH
INFORMATION  DESCRIPTION   VARCHAR2          2000
```